# Pumpkin Bread - using Splenda instead of sugar

Tags: substitutions, pumpkin, sugar-free

I have used this recipe with sugar and it's wonderful.  When using Splenda the batter was too thick and I can taste the baking soda, which was a fresh box.  I was also a half ounce short of pumkin.  Any ideas how to alter it to use Splenda in the future?

- 3 1/2 cups all-purpose flour
- 3 cups sugar
- 4 large eggs
- 2 teaspoons baking soda
- 1 1/2 teaspoons salt
- 2 1/2 teaspoons cardamom
- 1 teaspoon baking powder
- 1 teaspoon ground nutmeg
- 1 teaspoon ground cinnamon
- 15 oz pumpkin purée
- 3/4 cup vegetable oil
- 2/3 cup water

Answer (score 1):

Splenda [makes 1 for 1 sweeteners](https://www.splenda.com/product/splenda-granulated-sweetener/) for baking.

> Can be used for baking and cooking. It measures and pours just **1-to-1 like sugar**. 1 cup of Splenda Original Granulated Sweetener is equal in sweetness to 1 cup of sugar.

In [high sugar recipes](https://www.splenda.com/baking-tips-for-splenda-original-sweeteners/), they recommend mixing with sugar:

> In recipes where the amount of sugar is quite high, sugar often contributes significantly to the structure and texture. So, for frosting, candy, fudge, caramel, pecan pies, angel food or pound cake, you’ll get the best results when you only **replace about 25% of the sugar** required with Splenda Original Granulated Sweetener instead of a full sugar replacement.

I buy the Splenda product, but I’m not directly or indirectly connect in any way.